# How to edit Weblogic startup scripts to enable the JMX?

Tags: java, weblogic, jmx, zabbix

I am new to Weblogic. And I want to enable the JMX on Weblogic 12c.
As I searched on stackoverflow, I found this:

> Add the following JVM parameters to your Weblogic startup scripts:
>
> ```
> -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8888 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
> ```

However I couldn't find this script.
So where is it?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few weblogic startup (and shutdown scripts), one for Windows (ending in "cmd") and one for Unix/Linux (ending in "sh"). The filename begins [`startWebLogic`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs90/server_start/overview.html) and it was installed in your `weblogic/bin` folder.

Per the documentation (linked above),

> The `startWebLogic` script does the following:
>
> Sets environment variables by invoking DOMAIN_NAME\bin\setDomainEnv.cmd (setDomainEnv.sh on UNIX), where DOMAIN_NAME is the directory in which you located the domain; for example, WL_HOME\user_projects\domains\DOMAIN_NAME, and where WL_HOME is the location in which you installed WebLogic Server.
>
> Invokes the java weblogic.Server command, which starts a JVM that is configured to run a WebLogic Server instance.

Comment: In WL_HOME\user_projects\domains\DOMAIN_NAME\bin I find this file. Thanks very much!